# How to set jti claim in JWT token generated by Spring authorization server?

Tags: jwt, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to integrate Spring Authorization server and was trying to generate the JWT token using client_credentials grant type. But while token introspection, I can observe that the token has following claims information:

{
"sub": "testClientAK2",
"aud": "testClientAK2",
"nbf": 1694598773,
"scope": [
"System",
"SelfManage"
],
"iss": "http://localhost:9000",
"exp": 1694599773,
"iat": 1694598773
}
and there is no jti set in the claims.

On debugging, I could observe that the method public Jwt generate(OAuth2TokenContext context) in JwtGenerator does not set the claim jti.

Is there any way to set the same in the token?
Also, what is the difference between JwtGenerator and OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator in spring authorization server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can customize claims of the JWT according to example in the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer). Note that if you're **only** customizing claims, you only need to publish a `OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext>` `@Bean` (no need to publish a `OAuth2TokenGenerator` as well).

You can read about [`OAuth2TokenGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-generator) in the reference docs as well, which states:

> The provided implementations are `OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator`, `OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator`, and `JwtGenerator`. The `OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator` generates an "opaque" (`OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE`) access token, and the `JwtGenerator` generates a Jwt (`OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED`).

Comment: So jti, even being a default claim is not provided by default?

Comment: Also, I am not really sure which is desirable in my use case. JWTGenerator or OAuth2TokenGenerator. I am looking for JWT tokens only

Comment: The `jti` claim is only set in `OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator` which is for opaque tokens. It is not set as a claim in the JWT with `JwtGenerator`, but you can set it if desired using the customizer, as mentioned in my answer. I'm not sure what you mean by "default claim" in this context? Can you point to a specification you're referring to? Feel free to suggest adding the `jti` claim to the generated JWT by opening an issue on GitHub, if you believe there's a need for it. Just make sure you can provide a use case in detail as that will help us understand and prioritize the enhancement request.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-token-claims#registered-claims. Though these are Optional but the document says "The JWT specification defines seven reserved claims that are not required, but are recommended to allow interoperability with third-party applications. "

Comment: Ok, so not a spec but a recommendation by Auth0. Thanks! I think it would be worth opening an issue for that to discuss whether it should be added by default.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for considering the same